# No puedo ver el reloj digital

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio y no puedo ver el reloj digital que he insertado en el código.

Por favor, me pueden ayudar?.

Muchas gracias.

```js
function mostrarSaludo(){ 
  var fecha = new Date(); 
  var hora = fecha.getHours(); 
  if(hora >= 0 && hora < 12){ 
    texto = "Buenos Días"; 
    imagen = "img/mañana.png"; 
  } 
  if(hora >= 12 && hora < 18){ 
    texto = "Buenas Tardes"; 
    imagen = "img/tarde.png"; 
  } 
  if(hora >= 18 && hora < 24){ 
    texto = "Buenas Noches"; 
    imagen = "img/noche.png"; 
  } 
  document.images["tiempo"].src = imagen;
  document.getElementById('txtsaludo').innerHTML = texto; 
} 

function startTime(){ 
  var hoy = new Date(); 
  var h = hoy.getHours(); 
  var m = hoy.getMinutes(); 
  var s = hoy.getSeconds(); 
  h= checkTime(h); 
  m= checkTime(m); 
  s= checkTime(s); 
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =(""+ h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
  console.log(h + ":" + m + ":" + s +""); 
  setInterval(startTime(), 1000); 
  //setInterval(start, 1000); 
} 

function checkTime(i) { 
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i}; // añade cero delante en los numeros < 10 
  return i; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ventana</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  </head>

  <body class="w3-container w3-center" onload="mostrarSaludo()">
    <div onclick="startTime()">
      <p id="txt">Reloj:</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="saludo" class="">
        <img class="" name="tiempo">
        <div id="txtsaludo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ventana.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: puedes poner el error del editor tal cual? y qué editor estás usando? y la función startTime()

Comment: cuál se supone que es la imagen del reloj digital que no puedes ver en el código?

Comment: Hola Iria, la función recoge la hora del reloj local de la máquina cliente.

Comment: Hola Iria, te adjunto la referencia: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock

Comment: sabes hacer un debugging? añade console.log(document.getElementById('txt')); antes y después de document.getElementById('txt').InnerHTML, abre la consola en el navegador y dime que te sale al ejecutar

Comment: prueba h.ToString(), a ver si puedes ver las horas al menos

Comment: y otra cosa, coge tu función, la que has copiado y pegado aquí y compara con lo que hay en el enlace que has pasado, verás diferencias al menos en setInterval(startTime(), 1000);  esa línea

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por vuestros consejos, ya me funciona, a ver si por lo menos puedo añadir el script, o un pantallazo.

Answer (score 1):

Añado una imagen de script, ya me funciona.

Muchas gracias

```js
function mostrarSaludo(){ 
  var fecha = new Date(); 
  var hora = fecha.getHours(); 
  if(hora >= 0 && hora < 12){ 
    texto = "Buenos Días"; 
    imagen = "img/mañana.png"; 
  } 
  if(hora >= 12 && hora < 18){ 
    texto = "Buenas Tardes"; 
    imagen = "img/tarde.png"; 
  } 
  if(hora >= 18 && hora < 24){ 
    texto = "Buenas Noches"; 
    imagen = "img/noche.png"; 
  } 
  document.images["tiempo"].src = imagen;
  document.getElementById('txtsaludo').innerHTML = texto; 
} 

function startTime(){ 
  var hoy = new Date(); 
  var h = hoy.getHours(); 
  var m = hoy.getMinutes(); 
  var s = hoy.getSeconds(); 
  h= checkTime(h); 
  m= checkTime(m); 
  s= checkTime(s); 
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =(""+ h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
  console.log(h + ":" + m + ":" + s +""); 
  setInterval(startTime(), 1000); 
  //setInterval(start, 1000); 
} 

function checkTime(i) { 
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i}; // añade cero delante en los numeros < 10 
  return i; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ventana</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  </head>

  <body class="w3-container w3-center" onload="mostrarSaludo()">
    <div onclick="startTime()">
      <p id="txt">Reloj:</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="saludo" class="">
        <img class="" name="tiempo">
        <div id="txtsaludo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ventana.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

```js
function mostrarSaludo(){ 
  var fecha = new Date(); 
  var hora = fecha.getHours(); 
  if(hora >= 0 && hora < 12){ 
    texto = "Buenos Días"; 
    imagen = "img/mañana.png"; 
  } 
  if(hora >= 12 && hora < 18){ 
    texto = "Buenas Tardes"; 
    imagen = "img/tarde.png"; 
  } 
  if(hora >= 18 && hora < 24){ 
    texto = "Buenas Noches"; 
    imagen = "img/noche.png"; 
  } 
  document.images["tiempo"].src = imagen;
  document.getElementById('txtsaludo').innerHTML = texto; 
} 

function startTime(){ 
  var hoy = new Date(); 
  var h = hoy.getHours(); 
  var m = hoy.getMinutes(); 
  var s = hoy.getSeconds(); 
  h= checkTime(h); 
  m= checkTime(m); 
  s= checkTime(s); 
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =(""+ h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
  console.log(h + ":" + m + ":" + s +""); 
  setInterval(startTime(), 1000); 
  //setInterval(start, 1000); 
} 

function checkTime(i) { 
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i}; // añade cero delante en los numeros < 10 
  return i; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ventana</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  </head>

  <body class="w3-container w3-center" onload="mostrarSaludo()">
    <div onclick="startTime()">
      <p id="txt">Reloj:</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="saludo" class="">
        <img class="" name="tiempo">
        <div id="txtsaludo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ventana.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

```js
function mostrarSaludo(){ 
  var fecha = new Date(); 
  var hora = fecha.getHours(); 
  if(hora >= 0 && hora < 12){ 
    texto = "Buenos Días"; 
    imagen = "img/mañana.png"; 
  } 
  if(hora >= 12 && hora < 18){ 
    texto = "Buenas Tardes"; 
    imagen = "img/tarde.png"; 
  } 
  if(hora >= 18 && hora < 24){ 
    texto = "Buenas Noches"; 
    imagen = "img/noche.png"; 
  } 
  document.images["tiempo"].src = imagen;
  document.getElementById('txtsaludo').innerHTML = texto; 
} 

function startTime(){ 
  var hoy = new Date(); 
  var h = hoy.getHours(); 
  var m = hoy.getMinutes(); 
  var s = hoy.getSeconds(); 
  h= checkTime(h); 
  m= checkTime(m); 
  s= checkTime(s); 
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =(""+ h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
  console.log(h + ":" + m + ":" + s +""); 
  setInterval(startTime(), 1000); 
  //setInterval(start, 1000); 
} 

function checkTime(i) { 
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i}; // añade cero delante en los numeros < 10 
  return i; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ventana</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  </head>

  <body class="w3-container w3-center" onload="mostrarSaludo()">
    <div onclick="startTime()">
      <p id="txt">Reloj:</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="saludo" class="">
        <img class="" name="tiempo">
        <div id="txtsaludo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ventana.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

```js
function mostrarSaludo(){ 
  var fecha = new Date(); 
  var hora = fecha.getHours(); 
  if(hora >= 0 && hora < 12){ 
    texto = "Buenos Días"; 
    imagen = "img/mañana.png"; 
  } 
  if(hora >= 12 && hora < 18){ 
    texto = "Buenas Tardes"; 
    imagen = "img/tarde.png"; 
  } 
  if(hora >= 18 && hora < 24){ 
    texto = "Buenas Noches"; 
    imagen = "img/noche.png"; 
  } 
  document.images["tiempo"].src = imagen;
  document.getElementById('txtsaludo').innerHTML = texto; 
} 

function startTime(){ 
  var hoy = new Date(); 
  var h = hoy.getHours(); 
  var m = hoy.getMinutes(); 
  var s = hoy.getSeconds(); 
  h= checkTime(h); 
  m= checkTime(m); 
  s= checkTime(s); 
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =(""+ h + ":" + m + ":" + s);
  console.log(h + ":" + m + ":" + s +""); 
  setInterval(startTime(), 1000); 
  //setInterval(start, 1000); 
} 

function checkTime(i) { 
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i}; // añade cero delante en los numeros < 10 
  return i; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ventana</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  </head>

  <body class="w3-container w3-center" onload="mostrarSaludo()">
    <div onclick="startTime()">
      <p id="txt">Reloj:</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="saludo" class="">
        <img class="" name="tiempo">
        <div id="txtsaludo"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ventana.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

```js
function mostrarSaludo(){
  var fecha = new Date(); 
  var hora = fecha.getHours();
  if(hora >= 0 && hora < 12){
    texto = "Buenos Días";
    imagen = "img/mañana.png";
  }
  if(hora >= 12 && hora < 18){
    texto = "Buenas Tardes";
    imagen = "img/tarde.png";
  }
  if(hora >= 18 && hora < 24){
    texto = "Buenas Noches";
    imagen = "img/noche.png";
  }
  document.images["tiempo"].src = imagen;
  document.getElementById('txtsaludo').innerHTML = texto;
}
var start=function startTime(){
  var hoy = new Date();
  var h = hoy.getHours();
  var m = hoy.getMinutes();
  var s = hoy.getSeconds();
  h= checkTime(h);
  m= checkTime(m);
  s= checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =""+ h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
}
function reloj(){
    setInterval(start, 1000);
}
function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // añade cero delante en los numeros < 10
  return i;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Ventana</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>
<body class="w3-container w3-center" onload="reloj(); mostrarSaludo();" >
 <p class="w3-panel w3-border w3-pale-green w3-border-green" id="txt"></p>
    <div class="w3-panel w3-border w3-pale-green w3-border-green w3-padding-16">
    <div id="saludo" class="">
        <img class="" name="tiempo">
     <div id="txtsaludo"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ventana.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```